# How to display a description text image for 3 seconds in Dom?

Tags: javascript, dom, scripting

Hi I'm working on a site. I need help making a text appear in a div where it saids any image clicked their title and size. in DOM scripting. Can anyone help? No innerhtml.

Thanks

Comment: generally you'll get help here fixing something you have that doesn't work. what have you tried?

Comment: function showCredit(whichpic,x,y){
 var source = whichpic.getElementsByTagName("img"); 
 var title = source.getAttribue("src"); 
 var size = source.getAttribute("width","height"); 
 
 document.write(title + size); 
 
}
 
 function prepareTimers() {
    setTimeout(showCredit,4000);
   }
   window.onload = prepareTimers

Answer (score 1):

using pure dom scripting and no helper framework like jquery, gotta dust off some things I haven't used in awhile!

That said here ya go.  Must be placed after page has loaded.  (Or remove the last "showCredit();" line and put it in your body onload.

Note you'll need to alter this, I just put the "source" in the text, other attributes and styling is up to you.

```
function showCredit(){

    //find all image tags we want
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('img')

    //iterate through them
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length;i++){
        //bind the onclick function to all image tags
        elements[i].onclick=function(){
            //create the new div
            var el = document.createElement('div')

            //alter this to be whatever text you want
            var text = document.createTextNode('Source = '+this.getAttribute('src'));

            //alter this if you're going to have more than one clickable div
            el.id = 'test';

            //add the text to the div
            el.appendChild(text);

            //add the new div after the image tag
            this.parentNode.insertBefore(el, this.nextSibling);

            //set a timer to find the element we've named "test" and remove it
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                var element = document.getElementById('test');
                if(element){
                    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
                }
            }, 4000);
    }
    }
}

//execute the function (bind all images)
showCredit();
```

Comment: Great code, to complete the OP request here is the line with title and size: document.createTextNode('Source = '+this.getAttribute('src') + ', title: ' + this.title + ', size: ' + this.offsetWidth + 'x' + this.offsetHeight );